# Updating Values in FIelds of ArcGIS editing only portion?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have total 96 records which are having duplicate values like 999999.

What i want is to convert these values into unique ones like 999901,999902,999903 and so on, through the 96 records.

I want only 2 digits to be replaced as rowids but there may also be cases where i have to change three digits too.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the last part (2 digits vs. 3 digits?) but would you be able to just Field Calculate the field to `"9999"+str(!OBJECTID!).zfill(2)` if your _OBJECTID_ or _FID_ already increments from 1-96?

Comment: I wanted to mention that i dont want to change the length of the digits , i just want to change the numbers . as i have 96 duplicates of 999999 and i want to remove them. for three digits i wanted to know that if i will have 200 duplicates of the 999999 , than i will have to start it by 999001,999002 like this .

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from the [Calculate Field Examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3F8CD77A9F647ABBA678A76ADB86E15) in the ESRI Help Docs about incrementing calculations, here is a Field Calculator example that works for a user-defined number of padding.

**Important!** You need to change the `pPad` variable to the number of digits you want to right-pad (e.g. 2 or 3). This will maintain 6 total digits no matter how many values you pad.

**Code Block**

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
    pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
    pPad = 2 #adjust right-padded value, if req'd
    if (rec == 0): 
        rec = pStart 
    else: 
        rec = rec + pInterval 
    return "999999"[:-pPad] + str(rec).zfill(pPad)
```

**Expression Line**

```
autoIncrement()
```

**Parser**

```
Python
```

[image: Field Calculator]